# Début d'une phrase avec car, parce que, puisque et comme : différences ?

Tags: usage, conjonctions

J'ai rencontré la citation (Jules Romains)

> Car on m’écoute avec attention.

J'ai cru que *car* ne peut pas commencer une phrase. Pourquoi l'auteur l'utilise ici ?

**EDIT**

Je ne connais pas le nom du livre. J'ai rencontré cette citation dans un livre de grammaire pour des anglophones. On la trouve dans la section de conjonctions de coordination. L'auteur la traduit par

> For they are listening to me attentively.

---

**EDIT 2**

Finalement, je l'ai trouvé ; page 77 du livre Lucienne :

https://ia902905.us.archive.org/26/items/lucienne00romauoft/lucienne00romauoft_bw.pdf

> Et voilà qu'au contraire sa présence ajoutée à celle de la famille me
> donne plus de goût à jouer, m'empêche de glisser à une facilité
> ennuyeuse, me fait considérer chaque ligne de la partition comme une
> aventure intéressante, dont il y a du mérite et du plaisir à se tirer.
> Sa présence agit comme un piment. Je suppose même qu'on m'écouterait
> moins bien s'il n'était pas là. **Car on m'écoute avec une
> attention inespérée, que je sens venir sur moi, affluer sur moi, qui
> me soutient, qui reçoit et renvoie les mouvements de mon jeu avec une
> sorte d'élasticité, et qui va se répandre jusque sur les deux pages
> grandes ouvertes de mon cahier de musique, comme pour y aviver la
> lumière et comme pour en exciter le sens.**

---

De plus, quelles sont les différences parmi les phrases suivantes ?

> Car on m’écoute avec attention.
>
> Puisqu'on m'écoute avec attention.
>
> Parce qu'on m'écoute avec attention.
>
> Comme on m'écoute avec attention.

Comment: A few points to note: 1) You essentially cannot start a sentence with "car" unless the clause is meant as a *continuation* clause from a preceding one. 2) As for "puisque", there's another usage, as in:  "Puisque je te le dis !" 3) While you're at it, it might be worthwhile to add "comme" to your list.

Comment: D'où vient cette citation ? de Jules Romains ?

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, il vient de cet auteur.

Comment: Introuvable... un lien ?

Comment: Malheureusement, je n'en ai pas un. Je ne connais pas non plus le nom du livre. J'ai rencontré cette citation dans un livre de grammaire. On la trouve dans la section de conjonctions de coordination. L'auteur la traduit par **For they are listening to me attentively.**

Comment: Jusqu'à preuve du contraire, il s'agit d'une citation fantaisiste...

Comment: Though "car" and "for" are used in different registers, it can be said that "car" works like "for" in English, *for* they are both used to introduce a reason for something just mentioned in the preceding main clause. And they don't usually come at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: @jlliagre  Il est propable qu'il vient de Lucienne  ; cependant je n'ai pas trouvé le passage complet.

Comment: @jlliagre " Car on m'écoute avec une attention inespérée, que je sens venir sur moi. affluer sur moi, qui me soutient, qui reçoit et ..."  https://www.google.com/search?biw=1482&bih=720&tbm=bks&ei=rZQtXdexMKuSlwTjsbSADg&q=Car+on+m%E2%80%99%C3%A9coute+avec+attention+jules+romains&oq=Car+on+m%E2%80%99%C3%A9coute+avec+attention+jules+romains&gs_l=psy-ab.3...14258.17400.0.17695.14.14.0.0.0.0.242.1379.3j7j1.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.1.165...33i10k1.0.k4z6RUCvJDQ

Comment: @jlliagre https://ia902905.us.archive.org/26/items/lucienne00romauoft/lucienne00romauoft_bw.pdf

Comment: @jlliagre Après un peu près d'une année je l'ai trouvé :-)! (voir question actualisée)

Comment: Bien vu. @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens a donc déjà répondu sur *car* en début de phrase: *unless the clause is meant as a continuation clause from a preceding one*, ce qui est clairement le cas ici.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"puisque" apporte une légitimité à la cause, une certaine notion d'évidence ou le rappel que la cause est connue, ce que l'on ne retrouve pas avec les autres conjonctions. Il est courant que le "puisque" se place en début de phrase.

"Car" et "parce que" ont un sens similaire: ils expliquent un effet. "Car" est une conjonction de coordination qui ne peut en principe pas débuter une phrase. "Parce que" est une conjonction de subordination qui est peu utilisée en début de phrase, mais le faire n'est pas incorrect.

"Comme" et "Etant donné que" servent plutôt en début de phrase, ils introduisent un fait. J'éviterais toutefois d'utiliser "Comme" trop souvent à l'écrit, car il peut porter à confusion (il n'indique pas toujours une causalité). A l'oral cela passe bien grâce à l'accentuation.

Comment: Merci. Il me paraît que car est un peu plus soutenu, non ?

Comment: car est un peu plus formel et moins utilisé à l'oral qu'à l'écrit, mais je ne dirais pas pour autant qu'il est plus soutenu.